# How is the result of the expression (0==0<1<2<3>2>1>0==0) calculated in python?

Tags: python, expression, boolean-operations

Please explain how is the result of the expression `(0==0<1<2<3>2>1>0==0)` calculated in python.

Comment: From left to right. The [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#operator-precedence) explains this.

Comment: @TomKarzes Yes. It does evaluate this particular statement from left to right, as all operations in the statement are equal in importance, as supported by the documentation I provided. You're answering a question that hasn't been asked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unlike most languages, Python supports chained comparisons.  So the following:

```
0==0<1<2<3>2>1>0==0
```

is equivalent to:

```
0==0 and 0<1 and 1<2 and 2<3 and 3>2 and 2>1 and 1>0 and 0==0
```

You can read about it [here](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#comparisons).  The relevant excerpt is:

> Comparisons can be chained arbitrarily, e.g., x < y <= z is equivalent to x < y and y <= z, except that y is evaluated only once (but in both cases z is not evaluated at all when x < y is found to be false).